# how to fix this memory leak?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

```
- (void)addChild:(MyTreeNode *)newChild {
    newChild.parent = self;
    [self checkForSelectedNode:newChild];
    [self.children addObject:newChild];

}
```

In this code children is a property of the class used.The line
 `[self.children addObject:newChild];`

is showing 100 % leak when debugging with instruments. it is properly released in the dealloc method.still it is showing leak.how to remove this leak?

Comment: Are you using ARC?  Is `newChild.parent` declared weak?  If it's declared strong, you have a reference cycle.

Comment: no i am not using ARC.sorry i am a iphone beginner.i didnt get with the statement declared weak.(if weak typing is meant,then no i have used strong typing) how to fix this leak. i am having total 600kb+ leak in the code and almost all point to this line at the last...i am clueless ??

Comment: Run Analyzer and x=check for warnings.

Comment: To translate rob mayoff's comment to non ARC, is the *parent property of MyTreeNode declared as (assign) if it is not then that could easily be the problem.

Comment: Please who the header for `MyTreeNode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the header of `MyTreeNode` the parent property should be assign not retain. Other wise there are retain cycles and memory leaks.

Explanation: Down one level the node is retaining it's parent and the parent is retaining it's child. This retain cycle will keep itself from releasing.